# iOS: setFrame no longer working from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, ios6

I prefer to disable `autoresizesSubviews` and to use `setFrame` to place all of my subviews.
As of iOS 6, things seem to have changed a lot.
When I call setFrame on a view in `viewDidLoad`, there is no effect. I tried it from `viewWillAppear`; same thing.

A setFrame call will work in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, but that is not called initially like it was in iOS 5.

Can someone clarify please where I am expected to layout my views from?

Comment: Did you disable autolayout as well?

Answer (score 19):

I guess you want to layout your views from UIViewController. Have you tried performing your layout tasks in [viewDidLayoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

According to Apple's documentation:

> Your view controller can override this method to make changes after the view lays out its subviews.

Since your view itself does not do layout its subviews (you do not use autosize, autolayout or layoutSubViews:) you can do the layout tasks in this method.

Nevertheless, the elegant way would be to use a custom parent UIView and perform all the layout there, overriding UIView's `layoutSubViews:` (unless you add/removes views dinamically). Quote from Apple's documentation on ["How View Controllers Participate in the View Layout Process"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH13-SW2):

> **Ideally, the views themselves perform all of the necessary work to reposition themselves, without requiring the view controller to participate in the process at all.** However, if the view controller adds and removes views dynamically, a static layout in Interface Builder may not be possible. In this case, the view controller is a good place to control the process, because often the views themselves only have a limited picture of the other views in the scene.

Comment: Asking the views to lay themselves out doesn't make sense to me. Views don't have authority to say where they should go. That's the role of the controller, isn't it?

Comment: UIViewController has a a view property which points to a single view: the View Controller's content view. This single view is responsible for displaying everything what is related to your controller. In theory this single view knows all of its subviews and so does their layout. Please think about why the view controller has a method called "viewDidLayoutSubviews". Because layout of subviews should be the responsibility of THE (content) view. It is true that it is possible to layout the subviews from the controller too and it is not a necessarily a bad practice.

Comment: I've always found Apple's idea that autoresizing should be used to be kind of brain-dead. Haven't they ever read a book on user-interface design? An automatic view resizing mechanism will never produce the ideal layout of subviews. Layout has to be done by the person who designed the UI. The automatic approach is antithetical to good design, and I'm surprised that a company formerly run by Steve Jobs would advocate that approach. Maybe, if your only subview is something a table, automatic layout is appropriate. But if you've got a variety of subviews there is no point in automating layout.

Comment: I agree with you on this, although the new autolayout feature introduced by iOS6 is much more useful than autosize (but of course not backward compatible wit previous iOS versions). Anyhow, we are talking about doing layout from code here... If my answer helped (your first comment, which you later deleted, said that viewDidLayoutSubview worked for you) then please accept the answer.

Comment: Storyboard makes this issue relevant; I had a problem with a view loaded from storyboard, and repositioning something in viewDidAppear not working. Moving the setFrame to viewDidLayoutSubviews works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setFrame` in `viewDidLoad` if you uncheck the Autolayout option in Interface Builder. If you need to use auto layout, You need to perform your layout tasks in `viewDidLayoutSubviews:`.

[image: Uncheck Autolayout in Interface Builder]

Comment: Wow, didn't catch that. Thanks for the heads up, now I am doing all my early layout in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "Asking the views to lay themselves out doesn't make sense to me. Views don't have authority to say where they should go. That's the role of the controller, isn't it?". I think the answer is often negative. It's the parent view (not view controller) which usually plays the role of laying out it's own subviews. It does so by utilizing autoresizingMask or autolayout (iOS 6 only). Or You can make layout programmatically by overriding `-layoutSubviews` method of the parent view.

Sure, like Imre mentioned, controller can participate in the layout process as well by overriding `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I often use this approach when I don't want to subclass the top level view of the view controller for keep things simple.

Finally, I found this [post](http://kevin.dew.name/post/18579273258/where-to-progmatically-lay-out-views-in-ios-5-and) super useful. Even with some minor errors, the post provides a big picture of view layout process.